# replace "more and more" by something more formal

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, formal-language

I have the following sentence, which was said to me to be rather informal (to be used in an introduction sentence in a thesis)

> Electronic devices are getting more and more omnipresent nowadays.

What are alternatives for "getting more and more"? A standard replacement as "increasingly" seems not to be a good alternative in such a case.

Answer (score 4):

1. In formal discourse, *more and more omnipresent* or even just *more omnipresent* is unacceptable. *Omnipresent* means *present everywhere*, and *everywhere* has no degrees.
2. Moreover, you should ask yourself (I have no idea) whether your topic is the **distribution** of electronic devices or their **use**.
3. I imagine your critic's objection is not to *more and more* but to *getting*, which is still regarded as colloquial in this sense. Try *becoming* instead, or a paraphrase:

   > Electronic devices are becoming more and more widely distributed.
   >   Electronic devices are becoming more and more widely used.
   >   Electronic devices are more widely distributed than ever.
   >   Electronic devices are used more widely every year.
   >   Use of electronic devices is constantly increasing.

Comment: My final topic includes new device materials which can be helpful on the way to ubiquitous computing. Thus I want to say that already today the usage of electronic devices is widespread, i.e. we are on the way to ubiquitous computing and there new materials become interesting.

Comment: @user2758804 I would go with "use". The presence of devices is merely a constraint on their use, and it is their utility which drives their presence.

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on what Stoney said, you might want to consider using the word *ubiquitous*, rather than *omnipresent.* From NOAD:

> **ubiquitous** *adjective*
>   present, appearing, or found everywhere

As to your original question, you can shorten the phrase *more and more* to a single-word *more*:

> *Electronic devices are becoming more ubiquitous nowadays*.

or, you could use the word *increasingly*:

> *Electronic devices are becoming increasingly ubiquitous nowadays*.

Notice how I've replaced *getting* with *becoming*, to help further reduce the informality of the original.

Comment: Or just *becoming ubiquitous*, which avoids annoying people who think that *ubiquitous* can't be modified by *more* or *increasingly*--though the meaning is slightly different.